# How do I group route handlers in hapi.js

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

In my hapi.js application, I created a plugin for a collection of routes. The plugin contains in index file to define the routes, and a controller file to define the handlers. The following code is the starting point for the application.

`index.js`

```
exports.register = function (server, options, next) {
  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/coins',
    handler: require('./getCoins')
  });

  next();
};
```

`getCoins.js`

```
module.exports = function (request, reply) {
  reply('get all coins called');
};
```

This works as expected. The problem arrises when I try to combine multiple handlers into one file. The offending code from the two files (`index.js`, `controller.js`) is as follows:

`index.js`

```
var controller = require('./controller.js');

exports.register = function (server, options, next) {
  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/coins',
    handler: controller.getAllCoins()
  });

  server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/coins',
    handler: controller.createCoin()
  });

  next();
};
```

`controller.js`

```
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.getAllCoins = function (request, reply) {
  reply('get all coins called');
};

exports.createCoin = function(request, reply) {
  reply('create new coin called');
};
```

When structuring my code in this manner, I end up with `ERROR: reply is not a function`. It seems that the reply object is not instantiated at all. I can define each handler in a separate file and that would work, but I'd prefer to keep the handlers in the same file if I can. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**
Adding contents of `console.log(controller);`

```
{ 
  getAllCoins: [Function],
  createCoin: [Function],
  getCoin: [Function],
  updateCoin: [Function],
  deleteCoin: [Function] 
}
```

Comment: What is value of controller object in index file?  Use console.log, must be some problem with exports

Comment: I added the result to the questions to maintain clean formatting.

Comment: Very strange, are there any arrow functions used anywhere in your code?

Comment: none, I'm using glue to register the plugin. The directory structure is `root -> modules -> coins. The index and controller files are both in the coins directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the `handler: controller.getAllCoins()` line in the `index.js` file is expecting a named variable, not a function call. Changing that line to `handler: controller.getAllCoins` solved the issue.